# what are layer aware devices

Tags: http, networking, network-programming, mac-address

What are layer-1, layer-2, layer-3, layer-4 aware devices? What is the difference between them and what makes them belong to specific layer? I found very little on the internet

This is from the HTTP book I am reading:

> In Ethernet networks, HTTP messages are sent in the form of addressed
>   data pack- ets. Each packet has a layer-4 address, consisting of the
>   source and destination IP address and TCP port numbers; this is the
>   address to which layer 4–aware devices pay attention. Each packet also
>   has a layer-2 address, the Media Access Control (MAC) address, to which
>   layer-2 devices (commonly switches and hubs) pay attention.The job of
>   layer-2 devices is to receive packets with particular incoming MAC
>   addresses and forward them to particular outgoing MAC addresses.

Comment: Look up the OSI model.

Comment: nicee, that is the correct term to google